# The same program doesn't compile on Windows when using algorithm header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm learning C++.

I have written a program that compiles find on Ubuntu 18.04.2, but it doesn't on Windows 7 64 bits.

To compile on Windows I'm using Visual Studio:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017  Version 15.9.12
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.12+28307.665
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00369-90013-89248-AA631 
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2017

The errors I get are the following (when I add the `algorithm` header):

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5367): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5367): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5369): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(5369): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

When I double click on the first error, it goes to the third line of this piece of code:

```
        // FUNCTION TEMPLATE max
template<class _Ty,
    class _Pr>
    _NODISCARD constexpr const _Ty& (max)(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right, _Pr _Pred)
        _NOEXCEPT_COND(_NOEXCEPT_OPER(_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, _Left, _Right)))
    {   // return larger of _Left and _Right using _Pred
    return (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, _Left, _Right) ? _Right : _Left);
    }
```

And my code, that needs `algorithm` header (because I'm using std::find) is in the following method:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

std::string ConvertToAStarMap::TruncateMap(const std::string& robot_map)
{
    std::string truncatedMap;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> list;

    int current_x = 0;
    int current_y = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> map_cells = ConvertToAStarMap::split(robot_map, ';');

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = map_cells.begin(); it != map_cells.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> locations = ConvertToAStarMap::split(*it, ',');

        double x = std::stod(locations[0]);
        double y = std::stod(locations[1]);

        if (x < 0)
            current_x = static_cast<int>(std::trunc(x));
        else
            current_x = static_cast<int>(std::trunc(x + 1));

        if (y < 0)
            current_y = static_cast<int>(std::trunc(y));
        else
            current_y = static_cast<int>(std::trunc(y + 1));

        std::pair<int, int> current = std::make_pair(current_x, current_y);

        if (std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), current) != list.end())
        {
            list.push_back(current);

            truncatedMap += std::to_string(current_x) + ",";
            truncatedMap += std::to_string(current_y) + ";";
        }
    }

    return truncatedMap;
}
```

How can fix this error?

**UPDATE:**

If I include `Windows.h` header, I get the following errors:

```
warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

In the following code:

```
// Init max and min variables.
int max_x = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int min_x = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

ConvertToAStarMap.h => https://pastebin.com/PEHEvhSm 
ConvertToAStarMap.cpp => https://pastebin.com/Y4JWiyVU 
Main.cpp => https://pastebin.com/6LdQKVpP

Comment: FYI, `map` is a symbol in the `std` namespace.  You may want to use a different variable name.  See `<map>` header file.  Similarly with `list`.

Comment: Are you including `windows.h` anywhere?  That has a `max` (and `min`) macro that likes to break builds.

Comment: No, all the include are here.

Comment: So you're not using precompiled headers ?

Comment: FWIW this compiles fine for me with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.12.

Comment: @Rup, how can it compile ?  Necessary code is missing.

Comment: I have updated the question with the suggestion of @NathanOliver

Comment: @SidS I added a stub class declaration: `class ConvertToAStarMap { std::string TruncateMap(const std::string& robot_map); std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& robot_map, char sep); };` Unless split is inlined I don't think the rest of the class declaration matters.

Comment: Where in the list of includes did you place `windows.h`?  I've found that placing it last gives me the least amount of errors.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I placed the last one and the first one with the same number of errors.

Comment: I agree with @Rup - the error is not reproducible with the given code.

Comment: I have added all the code for the project.

Comment: Pick a different name for your `struct max`. There is a function `max` in the standard library std:: namespace and the Windows.h header defines a `max` macro unless you do `#define NOMINMAX` before you include the header.

Comment: @Blastfurnace That's the solution. I have changed its name to `struct max_coors` and now it compiles! Thanks a lot. By the way, I haven't added the `#include <Windows.h>` and it compiles also.

Comment: Congrats, `max_coors` is also a more meaningful name. Good names make better programs.

Comment: Yes, windows.h was a suggestion of what you might be doing wrong. Unless you're using Windows APIs directly you don't need it.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm getting a lot of troubles about how to name variables, classes, methods, etc. I came from C# and there I use Camel notation, but with C++ I don't know which naming convention and notation do I have to use.

Comment: The first thing you do in `ConvertToAStarMap.h` is `#include <Windows.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are having name collisions due to the `struct max {}` in your header. The C++ standard library has a `std::max` function template in `<algorithm>` and the Windows.h header defines a `max` function-like macro (unless you `#define NOMINMAX` before including the header).

I suggest you pick a different (and more meaningful) name for your `struct` to avoid the name collision.

Comment: `std::max` is not the problem. That’s why C++ has namespaces.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm open to suggestions to improve this answer. Would it be better to just say `max` and not mention the namespace? The library `std::max` can become a problem when doing `using namespace std;` or through ADL.

Comment: There is no indication he is `using namespace std;` He is doing an `#include <Windows.h>` before anything else in his header, though.

Comment: @SidS There's definitely no `using` statement in the posted or linked code. I just mentioned it as something that can lead to name collisions.

Comment: When I've changed the `struct max` with `struct max_coors`, without adding anything else (I have no added `#include <Windows.h>), it compiles. Maybe we have to ask to Microsoft why their compiler do such things.